# Automatic comment for low-quality flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

When deleting low quality answers from the review queue, you get the option to leave a standard comment, chosen from a list. I find it very convenient, and I think it would be useful to have the same feature when handling flagged posts, or also just browsing.

Is there a reason not to have pre-compiled comments?